# Google sheets script : Delete large number of rows that contains a specific data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a script to delete a large number of rows that contains a specific data (sheet has +80k rows). In this example I am trying to delete any rows that contains the value "Accessoires" in the 7th column.
I am pretty knew to this but spent quite some time looking for a solution everywhere on the forum.
So far I cam up with this code but this does not work
Any idea very much appreciated :)

```
var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var SHEET = SS.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var RANGE = SHEET.getDataRange();
var VALUES = RANGE.getValues();
var DELETE_VAL = VALUES.indexOf("Accessoires");
var COL_TO_SEARCH = 6; 

function main() {
  
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var deleteSelectedRows = removeThenSetNewVals();
  var runTime = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/1000;
  Logger.log("Runtime is: "+runTime + " seconds");
};

function removeThenSetNewVals(){
  
  var rangeVals = RANGE.getValues();
  var newRangeVals = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < rangeVals.length; i++){
    if(rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] !=DELETE_VAL){
      
      newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);
    };
  };
  
  RANGE.clearContent();
  
  var newRange = SHEET.getRange(1,1,newRangeVals.length, newRangeVals[0].length);
  newRange.setValues(newRangeVals);
};
```

Thank you very much for any help provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DELETE_VAL = VALUES.indexOf("Accessoires"); is a number.
RangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH] were text strings.

Also you wanted partial matches to count.
So the fixes were to make a string you are matching

```
var DELETE_VAL = "housse"; // a string
```

and then say (using toString to avoid saying indexOf on a number and getting an error)

```
if (rangeVals[i][COL_TO_SEARCH].toString().indexOf(DELETE_VAL) == -1){// text to avoid not found      
  newRangeVals.push(rangeVals[i]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked !! 
I thought I will be able to add values easily like in my smaller script but it does not seem to work here if I put "var DELETE_VAL = "housse" || "accessoires";". Is it not the correct way to show "or" values ?

Comment: To get into or's like that, especially with partial string matching, you want to look into using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let vo = vs.map(r => { if (r[6] != 'Accessoires') { return r; } }).filter(e => e);
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, vo.length, vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```